# gcc won't include libcurl on commandline for OS X

Tags: c, macos, command-line, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to compile a C project I've been working on on a remote server that runs OS X.  The project depends, in part, on libcurl.  I only have access to the machine through my administrator account remotely.

When I attempt to make the project I keep getting errors relating to libcurl functions and constants not being defined.  I conclude that libcurl is not being properly included by the compiler.

I'm using fink to install opensource software for all the dependencies ( postgres, curl, a few others ) and all the dependencies appear to work except curl.

My compiler command looks like:

```
gcc -ggdb -ansi -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -L `/sw/bin/pg_config --libdir` `/sw/bin/curl-config --cflags` -I `/sw/bin/pg_config --includedir` -lpq -lcurl -lpthread -lm `/sw/bin/curl-config --libs` -c Client.c
```

If I make a test file like so:

```
/sw/bin/curl http://www.google.com/ --libcurl test.c
```

And then attempt to compile it with:

```
gcc test.c `/sw/bin/curl-config --cflags` `/sw/bin/curl-config --libs` -o test.o
```

It also fails.  Can anyone help me shed some light on this problem?

Comment: I don't have fink installed, but your second example works for me with the system curl. I note in your second example you're sending the output to `test.o` but as you're not passing gcc the `-c` flag this may not be doing what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One compilation line is:

```
gcc -ggdb -ansi -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -L `/sw/bin/pg_config --libdir` \
    `/sw/bin/curl-config --cflags` -I `/sw/bin/pg_config --includedir` \
    -lpq -lcurl -lpthread -lm `/sw/bin/curl-config --libs` -c Client.c
```

This will take `Client.c` and generate `Client.o`, an object file.  It doesn't need the library information; there is no linking taking place because of the `-c` option.

The other compilation line is:

```
gcc test.c `/sw/bin/curl-config --cflags` `/sw/bin/curl-config --libs` -o test.o
```

It is aconventional to end the names of executables with '`.o`'; it leads to confusion.  However, if `test.c` only references functions from the standard libraries and libcurl, it should 'work'.

On my Mac, there is a copy of `curl-config` in `/usr/bin`.

---

Try this test program:

```
$ cat curltest.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (curl_global_init(0) == CURLE_OK)
    {
        printf("CURL version %s\n", curl_version());
        curl_global_cleanup();
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize CURL\n");

    return 0;
}
$ cc -o curltest $(curl-config --cflags) curltest.c $(curl-config --libs)
$ file curltest
curltest: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ otool -L curltest
curltest:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
$ curltest
CURL version libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
$
```

This is on MacOS X 10.6.8.

Comment: I have two copies of curl-config.  There is one in /usr/bin which gives a different output than the one in /sw/bin/.  Since /sw/ is the directory that contains all my fink installations I opt for that one.  Neither actually work in practice.